# r2_score giving wrong results?

Tags: python, correlation

I am having a strange problem, please can someone look at it:

I am doing some model fitting. To check how "good" the model is, I use r2_score from sklearn.metrics.

At some data-combinations, it seems to fail completly.

```
ref = [14.44600051978183, 17.561804553460263, 19.261334026375774, 20.39435367498611, 14.44600051978183,16.712039817002506,18.15663986898069,19.544588938528356,16.712039817002506, 17.84505946561285,18.97807911422319, 20.111098762833524, 17.84505946561285, 18.893102640577414, 19.82784385068094, 20.960863499291282, 17.76008299196707, 18.97807911422319, 20.05444778040301, 20.960863499291282, 18.12831437776543, 19.261334026375774, 20.39435367498611, 20.960863499291282, 20.111098762833524, 21.15914193779809, 22.0, 22.377138060054207]

pred = [13.12751026871668,16.234099798737148, 17.787394563747384, 18.5640419462525, 12.66840124840515, 15.666343879932109, 17.16531519569559, 18.66428651145907, 15.077797524003781, 16.520456140882633, 17.963114757761485, 19.405773374640333, 15.850036327506684, 17.23415013712082, 18.61826394673496, 20.002377756349095, 15.423479959829821, 16.770344482005054, 18.117209004180285, 19.464073526355516, 15.423479959829821, 16.770344482005054, 18.117209004180285, 19.464073526355516, 16.770344482005054, 18.117209004180285, 19.464073526355516, 20.137505787443132]
```

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
r2_score(ref,pred)

---> 0.05284238826655385

It should be a relatively good correlation, I would expect a r_squared value of approx. 0.9!   0.05 indicates about no correlation!!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[16,10])
ax.scatter(ref, pred)
ax.plot((12,24),(12,24),linewidth=.25,color="grey")
```

[image: ref to pred scatter plot]

If I calculate the R² score with

```
import scipy
_, _, r_value, _, _ = scipy.stats.linregress(ref, pred)
r_value**2
```

the result is more plausible --->  0.8811870529781631

Some other data combinations the r2_score "looks right".

What am I doing wrong?
Can someone confirm my results?

Comment: Can you show the code where you call `r2_score`?

Comment: Never mind my previous comment, I'll assume it was just the one line.  With `scipy` you're calculating the r2 from a linear regression (best fit), while with `sklearn` you're just comparing the absolute values.  The absolute values are quite far off.

Comment: I have added the import line:
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

anyhow: why does r2_score does not show the correlation? 0.05 is about no-correlation.
I have pretty similar data, where r2_score seems to give right answer. but not here.

what do you mean with "The absolute values are quite far off".

With my 5minutes of searching for an alternative, I was hoping to have found a "correct" method to calculate R-squared.

Comment: `pred` in this case is supposed to be *predicted* values, using the linear regression.  You didn't do a linear regression.